# Can WCF handle simultaneous calls to the same endpoint?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I am developing WCF application under Windows Service which is exposing one endpoint. There can be about 40 remote clients who will connect to this endpoint over local area network at the same time. My question is whether WCF can handle multiple calls to the same endpoint by queuing them? No request from any client can be lost.  Is there anything special I have to consider when developing application to handle simultaneous calls?

Comment: **YES, OF COURSE!** WCF would be pretty crappy technology if it couldn't do that!

Comment: "No request from any client can be lost." That's impossible. For example, the network might drop or your code might have a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose whether the requests should be handled asynchronously or synchronously one after another.

You can set this behavior via the `InstanceContextMode` settings. By default WCF handles requests *ByCall* which means one instance of your service will be created for each incoming request. This allows you to handle multiple requests in parallel.

Alternatively you can configure your service to spin off only one instance which ensures each request is handled after the other. This effectively is the "queuing" you mentioned. You can set this behavior via `InstanceContextMode.Single`. By chosing this mode, your service becomes a singleton. So this mode ensures there's only one instance of your service, which may come in handy in some cases. The framework handles the queuing.

Additionally you *could* set `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` which allows your single instance to process multiple requests in parallel (see Andrew's comment).

However, be aware that the queued requests aren't persisted in any way. So if your service gets restarted, the not yet finished requests are lost.

I'd definitely recommend to avoid any kind of singleton if possible. 
Is there anything that prevents you from chosing the parallel *PerCall*-mode?

For more details have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

Comment: If using Single mode, do I have to organize queuing myself or it's leveraged by framework? If by framework are there any means to tell when the next call can be serviced? What do you mean by "come close"? What are the restrictions? I'm now just assessing the limitations of WCF to see if it can serve my project needs.

Comment: For a complete answer, you should include single instance mode with ConcurrencyMode.Multiple https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here are some useful links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752260(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556230(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

To answer your question, no calls will be lost whatever you choose. But if you need to process them in order, you probably should use this setup for your service

`[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, EnsureOrderedDispatch = true )]`